# Why doesn't my JavaScript execute from my code behind?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, code-behind

Here is my aspx file: [Default.aspx](http://pastebin.com/uuWHjQRf) (I do not think this is relevant)

And here is my C# code-behind file: [Default.aspx.cs](http://pastebin.com/2BrjAG5D)

Here is my debug output. It shows that everything up to the JavaScript line gets executed:

```
[4476] aspx.page: Begin Load 
[4476] : Number of fields = 2 
[4476] : Page to load = Login 
[4476] : Session matched the supplied GUID! 
[4476] aspx.page: End Load
```

I am totally lost. I'd really appreciate some help!

Comment: You are trying to drive a boat on a road. It need water actually

Comment: Couldn't see your Code behind code, Pastebin.com gives error: "This website/URL has been blocked until further notice either pursuant to Court orders or on the Directions issued by the Department of Telecommunications"

Comment: Yeah I know its supposed to be executed by the web browser, but its not. My actual goal is to use ajax to inject another page into a div after user validation.

Comment: @Pankaj strange, well here is a mirror: http://pastie.org/4071836

Comment: @Mike: Use ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock Method (Page, Type, String, String, Boolean) instead of Page.RegisterStartupScript, its obsolete. for ex. ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page,this.getType(),"dummykey",alert('Hi'),true);

Comment: @PankajTiwari Nope, thaht didn't do it :(             ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page,typeof(Page),"dummykey","aler‌​t('Hi')",true);

Comment: @Mike: If you don't have ScriptManager in your page then ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock Method won't work, instead use this :ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "DummeyKey", "alert('Hi')", true);

Comment: Add an answer - since it appears that your suggestion worked for @Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Mike: If you don't have ScriptManager in your page then ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock Method won't work, instead use this :

```
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "DummeyKey", "alert('Hi')", true);
```